# Low performance of Elastic APM server

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, apm

I'm currently checking why the APM UI in Kibana doesn't output me the information when the timeframe is set to more than 24 hours.

When checking the config I did notice that we haven't had the Kibana endpoint set for the APM server.

Checking the APM logs I can't see an error but when going to the APM UI I can find this error in the Kibana logs:

```
kibana                    |{"type":"response","@timestamp":"2020-01-23T09:15:08Z","tags":["access:apm"],"pid":7,"method":"get","statusCode":400,"req":{"url":"/api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/services","method":"get","headers":{"host":"<our hostname>","connection":"keep-alive","sec-fetch-dest":"empty","kbn-version":"7.3.1","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.53 Safari/537.36 Edg/80.0.361.33","content-type":"application/json","accept":"*/*","sec-fetch-site":"same-origin","sec-fetch-mode":"cors","referer":"https://<our hostname>/app/apm","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"sl,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7"},"remoteAddress":"192.168.101.91","userAgent":"192.168.101.91","referer":"https://<our hostname>/app/apm"},"res":{"statusCode":400,"responseTime":30038,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/services 400 30038ms - 9.0B"}
kibana                    | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2020-01-23T09:15:47Z","tags":["access:apm"],"pid":7,"method":"post","statusCode":404,"req":{"url":"/api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/search","method":"post","headers":{"host":"<our hostname>:443","user-agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","content-length":"65","accept":"application/json","content-type":"application/json","kbn-version":"7.3.1","kbn-xsrf":"1","accept-encoding":"gzip"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1"},"res":{"statusCode":404,"responseTime":15,"contentLength":9},"message":"POST /api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/search 404 15ms - 9.0B"}
kibana                    | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2020-01-23T09:15:58Z","tags":["access:apm"],"pid":7,"method":"post","statusCode":404,"req":{"url":"/api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/search","method":"post","headers":{"host":"<our hostname>:443","user-agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","content-length":"30","accept":"application/json","content-type":"application/json","kbn-version":"7.3.1","kbn-xsrf":"1","accept-encoding":"gzip"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1"},"res":{"statusCode":404,"responseTime":20,"contentLength":9},"message":"POST /api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/search 404 20ms - 9.0B"}
kibana                    | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2020-01-23T09:16:17Z","tags":["access:apm"],"pid":7,"method":"post","statusCode":404,"req":{"url":"/api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/search","method":"post","headers":{"host":"<our hostname>:443","user-agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","content-length":"65","accept":"application/json","content-type":"application/json","kbn-version":"7.3.1","kbn-xsrf":"1","accept-encoding":"gzip"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1"},"res":{"statusCode":404,"responseTime":20,"contentLength":9},"message":"POST /api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/search 404 20ms - 9.0B"}
kibana                    | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2020-01-23T09:16:25Z","tags":["access:apm"],"pid":7,"method":"get","statusCode":200,"req":{"url":"/api/apm/settings/agent-configuration","method":"get","headers":{"host":"<our hostname>","connection":"keep-alive","sec-fetch-dest":"empty","kbn-version":"7.3.1","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.53 Safari/537.36 Edg/80.0.361.33","content-type":"application/json","accept":"*/*","sec-fetch-site":"same-origin","sec-fetch-mode":"cors","referer":"https://<our hostname>/app/apm","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"sl,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7"},"remoteAddress":"192.168.101.91","userAgent":"192.168.101.91","referer":"https://<our hostname>/app/apm"},"res":{"statusCode":200,"responseTime":17,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /api/apm/settings/agent-configuration 200 17ms - 9.0B"}
kibana                    | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2020-01-23T09:16:29Z","tags":["access:apm"],"pid":7,"method":"post","statusCode":404,"req":{"url":"/api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/search","method":"post","headers":{"host":"<our hostname>:443","user-agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","content-length":"30","accept":"application/json","content-type":"application/json","kbn-version":"7.3.1","kbn-xsrf":"1","accept-encoding":"gzip"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1"},"res":{"statusCode":404,"responseTime":17,"contentLength":9},"message":"POST /api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/search 404 17ms - 9.0B"}
kibana                    | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2020-01-23T09:16:47Z","tags":["access:apm"],"pid":7,"method":"post","statusCode":404,"req":{"url":"/api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/search","method":"post","headers":{"host":"<our hostname>:443","user-agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","content-length":"65","accept":"application/json","content-type":"application/json","kbn-version":"7.3.1","kbn-xsrf":"1","accept-encoding":"gzip"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1"},"res":{"statusCode":404,"responseTime":21,"contentLength":9},"message":"POST /api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/search 404 21ms - 9.0B"}
kibana                    | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2020-01-23T09:16:47Z","tags":["access:apm"],"pid":7,"method":"post","statusCode":404,"req":{"url":"/api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/search","method":"post","headers":{"host":"<our hostname>:443","user-agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","content-length":"65","accept":"application/json","content-type":"application/json","kbn-version":"7.3.1","kbn-xsrf":"1","accept-encoding":"gzip"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1"},"res":{"statusCode":404,"responseTime":16,"contentLength":9},"message":"POST /api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/search 404 16ms - 9.0B"}
kibana                    | Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms
kibana                    |     at /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:362:15
kibana                    |     at Timeout.<anonymous> (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:391:7)
kibana                    |     at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
kibana                    |     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
kibana                    |     at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
kibana                    |     at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
kibana                    | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2020-01-23T09:16:25Z","tags":["access:apm"],"pid":7,"method":"get","statusCode":400,"req":{"url":"/api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/services","method":"get","headers":{"host":"<our hostname>","connection":"keep-alive","sec-fetch-dest":"empty","kbn-version":"7.3.1","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.53 Safari/537.36 Edg/80.0.361.33","content-type":"application/json","accept":"*/*","sec-fetch-site":"same-origin","sec-fetch-mode":"cors","referer":"https://<our hostname>/app/apm","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"sl,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7"},"remoteAddress":"192.168.101.91","userAgent":"192.168.101.91","referer":"https://<our hostname>/app/apm"},"res":{"statusCode":400,"responseTime":30041,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/services 400 30041ms - 9.0B"}
kibana                    | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2020-01-23T09:17:01Z","tags":["access:apm"],"pid":7,"method":"post","statusCode":404,"req":{"url":"/api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/search","method":"post","headers":{"host":"<our hostname>:443","user-agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","content-length":"30","accept":"application/json","content-type":"application/json","kbn-version":"7.3.1","kbn-xsrf":"1","accept-encoding":"gzip"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1"},"res":{"statusCode":404,"responseTime":41,"contentLength":9},"message":"POST /api/apm/settings/agent-configuration/search 404 41ms - 9.0B"}
```

From the output it looks like that Kibana can't find any server configuration but the setup was done successfully but I can't as well access the APM settings that were moved in Kibana (timeout with error 404).

Other queries or the query from the same indices work well without any increased delay.

The APM agent is the latest version of the Django (Python) agent. And the resource metrics from clusters as well as status are really good, so the cluster should be powerful enough.

We have had as well testing deploy in Kubernetes and the services sometimes show up in the APM UI but it's turned off currently.

Environment and versions:

Elasticsearch deployed on GCP in Docker containers (4 nodes on different VMs + 1 VM with APM Server, Kibana, and Elasticsearch client node).

ES, Kibana, APM-Server versions: 7.3.1

Comment: A new issue has been opened in the Kibana repository as a reult of your question: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/55729 . However, you shouldn't be facing this kind of slowness anyway. What timeframes do you set APM UI to? (you say the problem appears when they are "more than 24 hours")

Comment: Thank you for opening the request. After further troubleshooting, I have found that the APM-Server has timeouts when clicking on the APM UI. 

The problem only occurs when going into the APM UI as the default time range is set to 24h if we change it to 12h or less it works every time. I will gather some additional logs and paste them here as well.

Comment: After analyzing the APM and Kibana logs I have found that around the search query from Kibana the APM server reports `pipeline/output.go:121 Failed to publish events: temporary bulk send failure`

Comment: and in elasticsearch I can see error logs about the monitoring index endpoint is used as in versions before 7.x `{"type": "deprecation", "timestamp": "2020-01-28T13:20:46,502+0000", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.d.x.m.r.a.RestMonitoringBulkAction", "cluster.name": "cluster", "node.name": "", "cluster.uuid": {id}, "node.id": {id},  "message": "[POST /_xpack/monitoring/_bulk] is deprecated! Use [POST /_monitoring/bulk] instead."  }` Could there be that the upgrade was not performed correctly from 6.x to 7.x?

Comment: Is it at all possible to share logs from all the involved components from a single time it fails? E.g. say a 10 min window from the logs of Elasticsearch, Kibana, apm-server and anything from the Python agent (if it has put anything to your app's logs). You can add multiple files in a Gist at https://gist.github.com

Comment: I have uploaded the logs that I had on my PC and combined both APM-server as well as Kibana logs. https://gist.github.com/falcon2k16/8a3865c4f17653b9fed2d6a9eee1167b  --when the logs were collected there were no error logs on Elasticsearch containers

Today we have made the update to 7.5.2 and as the index for APM (in the index name we have the revision of APM server) I could set up the settings for the APM client. Will check tomorrow if there is any additional indication. We have as well tweaked the settings for APM server, so we don't have any notice about the queue being full.

Comment: After some time the problem has re-appeared on version 7.5.2 with the setting of the APM set. The timeout now occurs on the endpoint /apm/services?start<timerange of 24h> and from the monitoring, I can see that the search latency goes to 1second for the cluster. Is there some problem with the whole cluster?

Comment: The indices are as well quite large see below:

APM span on a daily basis approx. 100GB of data and 160m doc count when writing down the index rate around 2100 /s

APM transactions on a daily basis approx. 40GB of data and 65m doc count index rate 800/s

APM errors on a daily basis approx. 8 GB of data 800k doc count index rate 25/s

APM metric on a daily basis approx. 1GB of data 3m doc count index rate of 50/s

APM onboarding really small number.